# Saving autoencoder output array as an image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have designed an autoencoder to read an (256*256) RGB image which gives an output as an array of float32 elements with dimensions (256,256,3) with some of the elements as shown in the figure.

```
img = Image.open('C:\\Users\\ece\\Desktop\\validation\\validate\\small_0002_7.jpg')
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
images = np.vstack([x])
classes = autoencoder.predict(images)
```

As I observed the output array values are in the range < 1. Now I want to to depict the output array classes as an image by expanding the values to the range of 256. What would be the best way to display the image?[output values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqD0D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The auto encoder should match the output amplitude to the input amplitude, so you probably have a preprocessing in your layer or your cost function also has a scaling factor.

To save your image, multiply the result by 255, cast it as `np.uint8`, then save it with something like `spicy.misc.imsave`.

Comment: Hi I used the following code lines before to reconstruct the image ---classes1=np.reshape(classes,(256,256,3))
img = Image.fromarray(classes1, 'RGB')
img.save('my.jpg')
img.show()   ----All it gives is a noisy image.

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid output image?

Comment: The autoencoder takes an input as (1,256,256,3). I have an output- "classes" which is float32 array with dimensions (1,256,256,3). The model is ok.. now the first issue arises as to how to pass the input validation image to the model. For this I have given the code line as shown in my post. And secondly, how to save--for which I used above mentioned code lines in my comment to your answer. Now I am not sure as to the source of error -whether I am wrongly passing the input image, or the representation of the output is wrong.

Comment: I meant to say, how do you check that the output image (before saving) is not noisy?

Comment: I have done something similar at https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/tree/third_edition/ch05. Making sure that the range is OK is not always intuitive.

Comment: Output will be noisy as it tries to reconstruct from a lesser dimensions. May be way too noisy too as there are less number of layers in the model. I suspect the noisy unrecognizable image is coming due to wrong casting of the ''classes'' array to ''img'' array which is only (256,256) in dimension : So issue is as to how to reconstruct an output array (1,256,256,3) as an (256,256,3) RGB image. I am now checking the link you provided.

Comment: If you start from a random state, then nothing will be recognized. But once the auto encoder is optimized (and you see that the loss function has reached a minimum), you should be able to recognize the object with the code I gave you.